# Не удаётся объединить данные из двух таблиц в одну YII

Tags: php, yii2

Имеется 2 таблицы org_special_price и incident
[image: Таблица org_special_price]

В таблице incident есть поле client_org_id
Я пытаюсь найти соответствия по org_id и client_org_id и если такое есть - добавить все столбцы из org_special_price

для этого я использую leftJoin

```
$incidents = Incident::find()
            ->leftJoin('org_special_price', 'org_special_price.org_id = incident.client_org_id')
            ->where(['incident.partner_org_id' => $org_id])
            ->all();
```

но затем - пытаюсь вывести для проверки во view через print_r($incidents) я нужных столбцов не вижу
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где моя ошибка?

Comment: `->select` мб добавить? а какие нить hasMany Отношения не хотите в модель добавить, чтобы а-ля `->with()` писать, а не ручками джойнить?

Comment: Спасибо! Добавил в моделе связку и связал через with!